# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stripe-signature')

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I encountered an issue while attempting to create a Firebase Cloud Function that handles Stripe's webhook events. Specifically, the function listens for the `checkout.session.completed` event, which is triggered when a customer has successfully completed a checkout process on Stripe.

However, I received a

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stripe-signature')

right from the start and I can't find a fix anywhere.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

const tokenValues = {
  price_1: 100,
  price_2: 200,
  price_3: 300,
};

async function updateUserTokensBalance(uid, priceId) {
  const tokensToAdd = tokenValues[priceId];
  if (!tokensToAdd) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid priceId: ${priceId}`);
  }

  const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
  const userDoc = await userRef.get();
  const userData = userDoc.data();

  await userRef.update({ tokens: userData.tokens + tokensToAdd });
}

exports.updateTokenBalanceOnPurchase = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    let sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

    try {
      let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        request.rawBody,
        sig,
        endpointSecret
      ); // Validate the request


      // If the event is checkout.session.completed, update the user's tokens balance
      if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
        const session = event.data.object;
        const uid = session.client_reference_id;
        const priceId = session.display_items[0].custom.price.id;

        await updateUserTokensBalance(uid, priceId);
      }

      // Return a successful response to acknowledge the event was processed successfully
      return response.json({ received: true });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err); // Catch any errors saving to the database or processing the event
      return response.status(err.statusCode || 500).send(err.message);
    }
  }
);
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It probably because of the way you are receiving request on `exports.updateTokenBalanceOnPurchase = functions.https.onRequest` . You would want to make sure you can receive any POST request (test by running a curl your self) before trying to integrate with Stripe

Comment: @orakaro Thanks. Actually I made a mistake when setting up the trigger. It should have been `HTTP` instead of `Cloud Firestore`. It works now.